# Capturing only a section of a command output

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

If I were to type a certain command, it would give me a long output in the terminal. I only need a few characters of this output. How do I, in a bash script, save only certain characters from a terminal output as a variable?

For example, if my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

ifconfig
```

I could save the whole output as a variable using

```
OUTPUT="$(ifconfig)"
```

But I only want my IP address copied, which is after `inet [IP ADDRESS]`

How would I go about doing this?

Edit: IP Address is just being used here as an example as I cannnot mention the command on here for security reasons, it's actually 'phrase: [five digit number]' in amongst other text and I just need that five digit number. Sorry for any confusion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Using `grep`

```
ifconfig | grep -oP '(?<=inet addr:)[\d.]+'
```

This uses grep's Perl-style regular expressions to select the IP address that follows the string `inet`.

So, to save that in a variable, just put both commands inside the `$()`:

```
output=$(ifconfig | grep -oP '(?<=inet addr:)[\d.]+')
```

The above will save the IP addresses for all active interfaces on your system.  If you just want to save the output for one interface, say `eth0`, then use:

```
output=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet addr:)[\d.]+')
```

#### Using `awk`

```
ifconfig eth0 | awk -F'[ :]+' '/inet /{print $3}'
```

`/inet /` selects lines that contain `inet`.  On those lines, the third field is printed where a field separator is an y combination of spaces or colons.

#### Using `sed`

```
ifconfig eth0 | sed -En 's/.*inet addr:([[:digit:].]+).*/\1/p'
```

### Alternate `ifconfig`

There is another version of `ifconfig` which produces output like `inet 1.2.3.4` instead of `inet addr:1.2.3.4`.  For that version, try:

```
ifconfig | grep -oP '(?<=inet )[\d.]+'
```

Or:

```
ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet /{print $2}'
```

Or, use this sed command which works with either version of `ifconfig`:

```
ifconfig eth0 | sed -En 's/.*inet (addr:)?([[:digit:].]+).*/\2/p'
```

Comment: `addr:` present in between `inet ` and the ipaddress

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks!  (I had answered  this while using debian -- sloppy of me.)  I just updated the answer to include methods for the ifconfig which prints `inet addr:1.2.3.4` while relegating the methods for the other ifconfig whose output looks like `inet 1.2.3.4` to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

ifconfig might disappear in the future, it is deprecated in some linux (maybe some ubuntu versions, but read on).

ip from the iproute2 package (should be installed by default) gives

```
ip addr list
```

and can be abbreviated to

```
ip a
```

and combined with

```
ip a | grep -o -P '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}(?=/)'
```

to filter on all IPv4 look alike numbers with a following CIDR mask slash.
If you don't mind about the broadcast, it even works in -E mode of grep, just leave the last brackets off the RegEx.

If you generally want to cut the cli output, and want to avoid piping it through cut ... (like in this example to get the first field)

```
IPS=$(ip a | grep -o -E '([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}' | cut -d\  -f1 - )
```

you could use bash string manipulation (like in the following example):

```
echo ${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}
```

This should give you a few clues where and how to start.

Comment: Your answer is OK , but can further be simplified to  `ip -4 -o  addr | awk '{print $4}' ` to list all addresses. Or `$ ip -4 -o  addr show wlan7 | awk '{print $4}' ` to show only `wlan7` for example. `-o` makes output formatted such that it's easy to process via `grep` or `awk` and `-4` gives only IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to print only the IP address regardless of interface using Grep; since that was the question

```
ifconfig |grep -o -P '(?<=addr:).*(?= Bcast:)'
```

addr: is the start string

Bcast is the end string

Anything in between those two strings gets printed using .*

Answer (score 1):

Using `facter`:

```
facter ipaddress
```